# how to set advanced search on an static page

Tags: magento-1.9, advanced-search

Searching by attributes is enabled and working fine. 
The case is that we made some changes in the main nav bar, by using url rewrite so we can use static pages or static blocks in the main nav bar.

Under this nav link, say "*products*" we have a category sublink "*camera*". Under the link "*camera*" we attached the right products.

The products are showing at the page as mentioned. But before these adjustments (when you clicked right at the category cameras) there is also the search engine to search a product by its attributes. Now it is not showing it anymore.

How can we get it back again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it, it works the same as a normal filter search. Just had to

> Set Is Anchor -> yes